# Take a snapshot with html5 webcam api and send by ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html5-canvas, html5-video

There is a way to take a snapshot with html5 webcam api and send by ajax to php server.

I really don't put code, because i don't know how to do it, I just have the basic: an html structue with the canvas and video element, the basic javascript template to show the webcam in the canvas, sorry about that, but really, really i don't know what to do, i mean what to code.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868621/unable-to-take-photo-from-webcam-using-html5-and-getusermedia-in-google-chrome

Comment: This is a tough one to answer because you need so many things to make it work. But it sounds like you have a path to get started. I would just learn each thing individually an then put it all together. I could throw you some code depending on what your missing.